# SQL-lite efficiency

Tags: iphone

I want to store my map data in the sql-lite database on iPhone. I want to use the "NSUserDefaults" class for this. What do you think? It will be efficient to ask the database manager to load the map everytime I need it? And how big map can I store there? Is there any limitations?
Thank you for the answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSUserDefaults should really only be used to store settings and not as a general data store. It's not a sqlite database. For storing your map data you could use Core Data.

Comment: Ok, that was my question. Thank you for your reply. Maybe can you give me some hint to very to start with core data or what is this?

Comment: Take a look here http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html. Basically, Core Data is a way of persisting objects to a database (or other storage). It takes care of most of the storage details for you.